# Is SemanticUI optimised to work with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, semantic-ui

How does SemanticUI goes along with AngularJS? I would like to decide which template to use, SemanticUI or Bootstrap. I have seen that there is some optimised Angular stuff done for Bootstrap by AngularJS: 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I'm not certain if I can use easy AngularJS with Bootstrap without that plugin. On the other hand, SemanticUI doesen't have this kind of feature for AngularJS yet. They have this, which is not ready for production yet:
https://github.com/angularify/angular-semantic-ui

Should that be a problem and do I even need that? I think about using SemanticUI or Bootstrap for html templates (I would use for backend something like Java or PHP) and if I am not wrong, JavaScript framework or library should not complicate the use of these templates.

I have seen on SemanticUI some JQuery code. But shouldn't JavaScript be handled by frontend developer.. why sould I even worry about JQuery or Angular?

As I realised, both SemanticUI and Bootstrap are templates with defined CSS classes. So they should both work good if it is used along any frontend JS, Jquery or AngularJS. Am I wrong?

Comment: semantic ui is css framework, angular is a js framework

Comment: I know that. I asked is it optimised.

Comment: css and js framework are 2 separate things with different concerns, bootstrap wasn't written to be "optimized" for angular any more then any other css framwork